# Should wait for next mint release for KDE plasma 5?

Tags: linux-mint, kde

I tried to find many way to install KDE plasma 5 on linux mint 17. but KDE 5 wasn't compatible on linux mint 17.

so should i wait for next linux mint release (mint 18) for KDE 5 ?

Comment: yes. that would seem to be your best option.